# Magento 2 : Rest API get product price including tax

Tags: magento2, tax, product-prices, rest-api

I have added tax rules to add GST on a product prices.

I have changed the store->configuration->sales->tax->Price Display Setting->Display Product Prices In Catalog to yes. I am getting it correctly on website when there is shipping address associated with quote.

I wanted to do same for the REST API.
Can anyone suggest better approach to accomplish this?

Comment: any progress ??